# System font size is small in high DPI display

Tags: display, release-juno

I'm having some issues with the system font on my high-dpi display.

I have a 15.6" 4K UHD (3840 x 2160) display, and despite having the font size in the Universal Access settings set to "Larger", I still find the system font hard to read occasionally. Is there a way to scale this larger?

Additionally, system icons don't appear to scale well -- ex, the network/Bluetooth/battery/notifications icons on the top of the display.

I'm using Elementary 5.0 (Juno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found that setting the text-scaling-factor [as in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi/272172#272172) helped *a lot* with my issues, including the application specific problems I was having. Didn't particularly fix the icon issues, tho.